# Assigning a local IP to docker containers

Tags: docker, networking, lxc

Is there a way to have docker automatically give it’s containers a local IP address that you can reach with it’s ports exposed?

For example, LXC has ways to do this.

```
lxc-create -t ubuntu -n myname
lxc-start -n myname -d
```

Which will then assign a local IP which you can see via lxc-ls if you have a bridge configured:

```
lxc-ls -f
```

This is super convenient for throwing up a bunch of containers for testing out deployment/configuration management like ansible.

Is it possible to do something similar in docker without much headache? I come from using LXC and I’m not familiar with the networking modes.

Comment: If I understood correctly your question, you can use `docker-machine` to have separate and different environments. you can access your containers using the IP of `docker-machine` you have started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LXC and Docker are very similar. When LXC is installed, a random subnet is picked for configuring the IP addresses of bridge and the containers attached to it. With Docker, the default subnet is `172.17.0.0/16`, which can be customized if needed. Every container stared (unless using host network or network of another container) using `docker run` command are assigned an IP address from the above subnet.

`docker ps` lists all the containers running but unfortunately it doesn't show the IP addresses.

Looks like a small trick can show the IP addresses: (based on this [post](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8786#issuecomment-60617278))

```
docker ps -q | xargs docker inspect --format '{{ .Id }} - {{ .Name }} - {{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}'
```

Also you can expose the ports using the `-p` option of docker run command.

Example:

```
docker run -itd -p 8080:80 nginx
```

This starts the container on the docker bridge and also exposes the nginx on the host network via port 8080.

```
from_host_running_container# curl http://172.17.x.y

from_not_the_host_running_container # curl http://${HOST_IP}:8080
```

Comment: Thank you! I wasn’t aware it was even doing that with IPs because I couldn’t see the details in docker ps